# scp a file to multiple folders

Tags: regular-expression, scp

I wanted to scp `file.txt` to remote box `my-remote-vm-1`

In `my-remote-vm-1` there are two folders `conf-1-ver-2`,`conf-2-ver-2`. The integer part in the folder name can go from `[0-9]`.

What would be the best way to scp `file.txt` to these folders ?
I have tried

- `scp file.txt my-remote-vm-1:/tmp/conf-[0-9]-ver-[0-9]/.`
- `scp file.txt my-remote-vm-1:/tmp/conf-*/.`

Both failed with `scp: ambiguous target`.

Comment: you can't to that so simply. It does not work this way. The best guess is to copy it to one place and then run some script to copy the file over different places on local system. But it stinks with bad design if you have to do such things.

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems a reasonable enough question for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Run `scp` once, then copy it locally on the remote server.

```
$ scp file.txt my-remote-vm-1:/tmp
$ ssh my-remote-vm-1 'for i in /tmp/conf-[0-9]-ver-[0-9]; do cp /tmp/file.txt "$i"; done'
$ ssh my-remote-vm-1 rm /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Looks like this is going to run the loop for 10 times even though I have only two folders at the destination.

Comment: @GovindKailas Ah, I wrongly read your problem... updated.  You need to run some script remotely anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If only **one** integer will change (as in your example) you could do this:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n" |xargs -n1 -i -P0 scp file.txt my-remote-vm-1:/tmp/conf-{}-ver-2
```

Answer (score 0):

might be too late, but maybe just for reference...

```
find -name "conf-[0-9]-ver-2" -exec scp file.txt {} \;
```

or more general

```
find -name "conf-*-ver-2" -exec scp file.txt {} \;
```